# How to draw a board with chalky lines?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I need to draw a playing area looks like a board and make lines (drown by chalk) on it (5x5 for instance) in such a way that I will be able to operate with squares.

How to accomplish such a task with WPF?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "drawn by chalk" so I'm gonna say repeat an image onto a bitmap to the size you want

Comment: You mean to draw a piece of image and then duplicate it?

Comment: basically yea, even store an image, load it, and repeat it

Comment: no problem, you will find other members more willing to help you if you have tried something first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a basic premise or starter point for you. Basically, you could just add an image to the container. Although this most likely isn't the most feasible way to go about this. It should hopefully give you a good starter point:

```
namespace DrawSomeStuff
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Point mousePosition;
    Image chalk;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get mouse position
        mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        //Set chalk
        chalk = new Image();
        chalk.RenderSize = new Size(5, 5);
        //Set chalk image

        //Move and add chalk
        chalk.TranslatePoint(mousePosition, this);
        this.AddChild(chalk);
    }
}
}
```